# Can't send a message trough UDP

Tags: android, multithreading, udp

Unfortunately I can't send a simple String message via UDP. The code is simple. I created a SendLocation class and I want send a location message with this. Everytime I try it, I've got the "can't send it" message. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

(messDelay, messCount, ip, port are EditTexts)

```
private class SendLocation extends Thread {

    private String message = "";
    private volatile boolean flag = true;

    public SendLocation(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (flag) {
            try {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Server.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                byte[] data = message.getBytes();

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, InetAddress.getByName(ip.getText().toString()),
                        Integer.valueOf(port.getText().toString()));
                for (int i = 0; i < Integer.valueOf(messCount.getText().toString()); i++) {
                    socket.send(packet);
                    Thread.sleep(Integer.valueOf(messDelay.getText().toString()));
                }
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Server.this, "Can't send it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the exception text, otherwise we will be guessing.

Comment: I would like to ask you where can I get the exception text?

Comment: when you catch the exception, there is information in the e. You can do: Toast.makeText(Server.this, "Can't send it: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  Or you can log the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for everybody. I solved the problem.